# Add Android Enthusiasts to the default migration targets, drop Gaming

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, migration

As Android devices become more popular, Super User gets more and more off-topic Android questions. To quote our FAQ (emphasis mine):

> If your question is not about...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - **electronic devices**, media players, **cell phones or smart phones**, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Fortunately, there is a dedicated site for [questions about Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/)! Unfortunately, it's not currently a site that 3k+ users can nominate for migration:

[image: migration options dialog]

Looking at the [migration stats](https://superuser.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) for the past 90 days, it appears that although Gaming is on the default list, very few migrations go there - only 4 in the past three months. The rest of the options are indeed the top 3 migration sites, not counting meta, which is a required option.

[image: migration statistics]

As we can see, Android is the next-highest migration target. I therefore propose that **Android be added to the list of migration options, to replace Gaming**. There is very little overlap between what is on-topic for Super User and what's on-topic for Android, so erroneous migrations should not be a problem (as they would be if Apple, Ubuntu, or U&L were added to the list).

Please vote below on whether this should be done. Anybody disagreeing can also leave their own answer.

Comment: [While you're at it](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions)...

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what the rejections rates of our migrations to the top sites are, would provide a better picture than just the raw number we can get ourselves, although I'm not expecting to see anything particularly alarming.

Comment: @DMA57361 Isn't there a network wide moderator chat room where you could ask this?

Comment: @DanielBeck Indeed there is. I'm just warming up in to my work day atm, so I'll pester them if I get a chance, just thought I'd drop that comment here before I forgot about it.

Comment: The responses I've had so far are SF:10%, WebApps:14%, Android:11% and Apple:7%, with no response from other mods yet. (For comparison SU's *inbound* rejection rates are: SO:9%/716, SF:12%/329, WebApps:9%/21 for our top three, the rest all count at 17 or fewer migrations in).

Comment: @DMA57361 SO replied that rejection rate was 10% as well

Comment: Android sounds a bit high for only moderator-approved migrations (compared to e.g. Apple). Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Yes, I support adding Android and removing Gaming from the migration options on Super User

<sub>**Please note**, I will view the vote split and only count positive votes, so downvoting the option you dislike won't make any difference.</sub>

---

*This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!*

> [image: Belongs on Android.SE]

Answer (score -7):

## No, I do not support adding Android and removing Gaming from the migration options on Super User

<sub>**Please note**, I will view the vote split and only count positive votes, so downvoting the option you dislike won't make any difference.</sub>

Comment: Challenge accepted! \*downvote\*

Comment: @nhinkle I like your way of stating the option. It matches your Spock avatar.