# Why was my question on RTF editing problems on linux closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question about a specific problem with RTF editing on linux with details about what I tried and observed, but my question was closed as off-topic.

[How can I edit huge RTF files produced by Windows in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/511476/is-there-an-rtf-editor-for-linux-mint-13-with-good-open-and-edit-performance-and)

The question is not open ended, or vague.   It is a specific question about troubles editing RTF files on linux.  The only thing I can think of is that I included details that the TextEdit program on Mac OS X has no problems in reading/writing/cleaning up my RTF files, and that linux enthusiasts didn't like that for some reason.

This is a real, specific problem with computer software, isn't this what superuser is for?

What modifications/suggestions can anyone suggest that would make it proper superuser material?

Comment: Please have a look at http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Comment: "Good" and "reasonable" are quite subjective.

Comment: @AlEverett so are votes to close!

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: then the site should have a "closed because the question requires recommending software", not "off-topic."  The off-topic FAQ makes no mention of "recommendations for software."

Comment: OK, so now I better understand the rules of the site, thanks.   A site for asking questions about software and hardware where requests for software to use a computer is disallowed.  OK, got it.

Comment: @Bogatyr: The FAQ sums it up under "shopping or buying recommendation".

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: that entry in the FAQ just didn't pattern match my understanding of my question.   It would be clearer if it read "any request for software recommendation."

Comment: @Bogatyr: You're not alone ;) http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your question to focus on the actual problem and getting it solved rather than asking for what text editors might exist.

Usually, you want to just state your problem as precisely as possible and let others figure out how to help you best, be it by offering workarounds, certain tools, et cetera.

Also, avoid using "good" or "reasonable", as Al Everett posted above.

Comment: Thanks and I understand now the difference between the two versions WRT site policies.