# What is the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Can someone explain with words, how is this question:

[NFS Server/Client administration of multiple machines through a GUI](https://superuser.com/questions/636562/an-nfs-server-client-gui-tool)

... off-topic from SuperUser?

---

Just to clearly point out that I've read the FAQ:

[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> computer hardware,

Nope, not for computer hardware, so probably off topic?

> computer software, or

Yes, about computer software, so on topic?

> personal and home computer networking

Yes, it was for home computer networking,  so on topic?

> and it is **not** about …
>
> programming and software development,

I didn't ask how to *program* such an application, I asked for already existing application, so on topic?

> video games or consoles,

Nope, so on topic?

> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

Nope - unless you consider anything dealing with a "network" to be a "website", which if you're extremely cynical, you might.. So on topic here?

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

Nope - however, a "computer" *is* an "electronic device", so a cynical reviewer could consider *every* question on SuperUser "off topic", hehe `:)`

> issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,

Nope - home usage, so on topic?

> asking for a shopping or product recommendation,

I'm asking about a GUI program to manage a networking file system for Linux, which as hopefully known, is free and open source, so no "shopping" involved. However, a cynical reviewer might consider mentioning *any* piece of software that runs on a computer a "product recommendation" - thus any question on SuperUser that is not expressed in terms of pure mathematical formulae would be off topic `:)`

[What types of questions should I avoid asking? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

> First, make sure that your question is on-topic for this site.

I think I did above; although as mentioned above, any mention of "electronic devices" and "product recommendations" is a qualifier for off-topic - so I wouldn't really know; which is why I'm asking.

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

There either is a GUI tool that can handle both server and client NFS administration, or not. If not, I do not expect an answer (apart from maybe "No such tool at the moment" - but I don't expect downvotes either). I don't see how that would qualify for "chatty, open-ended questions". I was looking, and I could find only one, server-side only, GUI tool which I referenced, so it's not like I was lazy or anything.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

No I cannot imagine a whole book - as I said; there either is a GUI tool of the kind I'm looking for, or there isn't.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

I cannot see how asking about an existence of a GUI tool would be inviting to participate in a discussion. Then again, I can always rephrase the same question as: "I would like others to explain how to manage both server and client aspects of NFS shares with a single GUI tool"; which will again boil down to: there either is a GUI tool of the kind I'm looking for, or there isn't.

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

I believe I didn't ask about favorite choices.

> your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Nope, never seen a tool of the kind I'm looking for, which is why I was asking in the first place.

> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

I'm totally not curious about other people's feelings - I just want to know if there is a GUI tool that manages client and server side of NFS sharing; and if so, which one it is.

> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

I don't think I did - although, if I was cynical, I could always rephrase as: "What if a GUI tool that can manage both server and client side of NFS shares existed?"

> your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

I don't think I had any ranty aspects in my question - apart from a slight disappointment that such a GUI tool doesn't exist, or if it does, it cannot be tracked down with a moderately thorough search. Again, if I was cynical, I could always reconstruct the meaning of my question to be: "Managing NFS shares through the terminal sucks, am I right? Better to use a GUI tool, no?"

So, taking the above into account-  as far as I can see, my question was on topic for SuperUser. But since the community insisted it *wasn't* I (and probably others), would be greatly appreciate an explanation of where did I go wrong in reading the FAQ (taking into account that there are enough possibilities to take pieces of the FAQ cynically, and thus declare any and all questions on SuperUser off-topic).

Comment: The question isn't closed yet, but it is of the type, "this is my unique environment, suggest a tool that I can use here"

Comment: @random - ok, I see; although I was just trying to explain what my motivations are; but what I want is really a GUI tool that can handle both client and server - that is not a web application, I'm not asking for instruction on network setup. Is there an appropriate site where I could move this question?

Comment: I removed the text considering unique setup in that question, hope it's OK now...

Comment: You can also "shop" for free software, e.g. *"What's the best free, open source video converter?"* – that's the kind of question we wanted to discourage with this particular rule in the FAQ.

Comment: @slhck - ah, I see - thanks for that clarification; I didn't connect the "what is the best..." prompt to "shopping" until now; it does make sense. However, that question still does not ask about _the best_ alternative - it asks for _any_ (if existing). Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

OK, I've deleted the question - hope you're all happy now, given how you downvote, and do not care about explaining what is wrong.

Comment: Quote from a diamond moderator, in a comment to your above question: `The question isn't closed yet, but it is of the type, "this is my unique environment, suggest a tool that I can use here"` - random ♦. I haven't seen the question, however it appears to be an opinion based question ("What's the best {thing}?"), and those aren't allowed on superuser.

Comment: I'm not sure your edit made the question *better*, it just now lacked important context. While I agree unexplained downvotes can appear confusing or even demotivating, having a question downvoted doesn't mean you should instantly delete it—it wasn't even closed. Now I'm not so sure if you actually want to discuss this… if you want to, here's a tip: don't throw the towel so quick.

Comment: I made an edit in order to hopefully improve the post, but your question is still deleted. If you want to have it undeleted, please flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - thanks for the comment; I wasn't asking for a _best_ alternative, I was asking for _any_ alternative; the software I cited handles _only_ server-side NFS; I was looking for a tool that handles _both_ server- _and_ client- side NFS; and as noted, I could _not_ find such a tool by now. Cheers!

Comment: @slhck - thanks for the comment; context is the reason why I included that text in the first place - but then I see closevotes as "Off Topic" without any further comments; and since only @\random responded with ""this is my unique environment" as a possible off-topic trigger, I thought it better to remove the text, so as not to trigger downvotes. I actually do want to discuss this, but I did get very frustrated by "Off-topic" without any further clarification; the edit in this OP shows why I think the question was on-topic. And I really put a lot of effort into writing questions on ...

Comment: @slhck ... these sites (because I truly appreciate all answers I've gotten so far, and I would hate to waste people's time). But getting "Off-topic"s, without further qualification after all the effort I put in to _be_ on topic, is truly frustrating, that is why I threw the towel. Of course I'd still want it discussed, and I'll flag for undelete - but should the original text with extra context be restored, or the edited post? Thanks!

Comment: Please search MSU for this, e.g. here: [Update the FAQ to disallow any product recommendation questions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3587) – the gist being, rather describe what problem you need to solve than looking for a magic tool you think solves the problem. This should be fine. We of course can't close all questions that may require some software as a solution (although some close voters might think so), but asking for a certain problem you have with software *X* is the way to keep these posts within our scope, or simply describing what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @slhck - thanks for the link, I have already seen the post - and although I somewhat got the gist of it, that post is also somewhat inconclusive. I guess this case is a bit of a gray area: if I formulate the problem as "I find command line NFS setup too difficult, is there a GUI I could use to make it easier", I would rightly expect a first order answer to that to be "get outta here, learn to type" `:)` So I add some info on context, but it turns out it is a trigger for "this is my unique environment" as off-topic; so I remove that, and I get even more off-topic closevotes; so I didn't know...

Comment: @slhck ... how to proceed really. Then again, the core of the problem could be understood as "NFS setup is too difficult", and given it's a difficulty with a network protocol, some may consider that as off-topic; but again, I'm not asking for help with the network setup - just a GUI tool applicable to it (both server and client side). I was just trying to keep everyone in the community pleased - but sometimes I guess it is not possible. Thanks for the feedback - cheers!